# Unsure how to structure by Android application

Tags: android

I'm a newbie to Android development, and am currently developing a game that consists of a grid with images.
So my main Game activity loads a GridView, which in turn is populated by a custom BaseAdapter I've extended. The idea is that when the user clicks an image that the grid is redrawn, then the AI makes a move and the grid is redrawn again etc.
So in my BaseAdapter, when I create an ImageView I'm setting a custom OnClickListener that performs some calculations and then invokes BaseAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged() to update the GridView after.

However, I'm unsure now as to where I should locate the logic for the AI's "move", and how can this be invoked? Instead of having a custom OnClickListener class, should my main Game activity instead implement OnClickListener?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your game is based on clicks on the `GridView`, I don't see anything wrong in keep the `OnClickListener` there. You might want to simplify the code inside the listener, though, and let it just call a function `nextMove()` in your `Game` class to handle the game logic.

Note that this class would not be your main Activity either (I would rename the Activity to something a little more descriptive than "Game"). Try to separate as much as possible the UI from the game logic. Obviously, the logic needs to respond to UI events, and change the UI accordingly, but the interrelation should stop there.

Comment: Essentially, what I have at the moment is a GameActiviy which delegates to a BaseAdapter which in turn delegates to an OnClickListener. However, I need to pass the GameActivity object to the OnClickListener to load dialogues etc. So effectively both the GameActivity and OnClickListener will be invoking methods on each other. Is this OK, or is there a better way of doing things? (I've ignored some other classes above for simplification)